# Creating orders programmatically

Tags: magento

I try to create an order in code, but sometimes the code works, but sometimes it goes wrong with exception "The requested Payment Method is not available." (first browser request is ok, but the second one goes wrong, etc..).

My code is:

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
} else {
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $email = 'test@example.com';
    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
    $customer->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
    $customer->loadByEmail($email);
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
}

$customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')
        ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
        ->getCustomer();

$customAddressId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling();
if ($customAddressId) {
    $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customAddressId);
}

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
        ->setBillingAddress(Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote_address')->importCustomerAddress($customAddress))
        ->setShippingAddress(Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote_address')->importCustomerAddress($customAddress));

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->load(2);

$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->truncate();

try {
    $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => 2));
    $cart->save();

    $message = $this->__('%s was successfully added to your shopping cart.', $product->getName());
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($message);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
$checkout->initCheckout();
$checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('register');
$checkout->saveShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');

$checkout->savePayment(array('method' => 'banktransfer'));

try {
    $checkout->saveOrder();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

$cart->truncate();
$cart->save();
$cart->getItems()->clear()->save();
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code in my local server, It s working fine 1st time, but second time it shows error like `The requested Shipping Method is not available` not like you mentioned above. But after I enabled that shipping method it working fine, So try to enable the shipping and payment methods that you used in your code in admin..

Comment: hmmm... it's so strange. I have the shipping method and the payment method enabled.

Comment: then, check your configuration scope.May you have enabled the shipping and payment methods for other config scopes..

Comment: No, I checked it and everything base on the default config values.

Comment: try to use different payment methods in your code, and dont forgot to enable that..And have a look at your order that created in first time, which payment methods taken for that order.

Comment: If I use ccsave there is no problems. Ohh.. I'm really annoyed this situation.

Comment: IF it runs first time and not second time, there will be not a error in the code but in Magento conditions, like product is not on store for next order, customer cant be created twice etc... and the paying method will be only result of another occasions ...

Comment: but on the third request it works again :). Finally, I've removed the 3 lines before the customer logout, and it works quite well right now.

Comment: I checked with almost all payment and shipping methods..It working fine.And I didn't removed any codes of you..Its really strange..